# Get value of html elements form a jquery $.post() data

Tags: jquery, html, .post

I have some pages that i acces by jquery $.post like this:

```
$.post(url, {name: name}, function(data)
{
    var htmldata = $(data);
    if($('#ok', htmldata).val() == "1")
    {
        //some things carried out
    }
});
```

`$('#ok', htmldata).val()` is allways `undefined` so where is the problem?

**UPDATE:** `htmldata = <input id=\"ok\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"1\" />` and another 2-3 hidden input.

Comment: Could you provide a real example of what is contained in htmldata variable?

Comment: this is contained it htmldata and another 2-3 hidden inputs: `<input id=\"ok\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"1\" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#ok', htmldata)` will look for all **descendants** of `htmldata` that have the id of `ok`.

You need to change `$('#ok', htmldata)` to `htmldata.filter('#ok')`

Comment: I totally agree.  Then, your source code would look like this: 

`$.post(url, {name: name}, function(data)
{
    var htmldata = $(data);
    if ($(htmldata).filter('#ok').val() == '1')
    {
        //some things carried out
    }
});`

Answer (score 1):

Actually no need to use `$` in the following line:

```
var htmldata = $(data);
```

Use directly `var htmldata = data;` and try to check whether any ata is there in htmldata.If yes then proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

Because data in htmldata is not initialized in DOM, if you want that work inject this into DOM  in hidden div for example.

But better approach is return JSON from AJAX and then check for status is very easy.

Of Course you can always parse using regex :)

Example of first case (not tested) - put this into callback function:

```
$("#ajaxData").remove();
$('body').append('<div id="ajaxData">' + htmldata + '</div>');
if(parseInt($('#ok').val()) == "1")
{

}
```

Comment: could you give me an example... this is my first jquery/ajax page:D

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$.post(url, {name: name}, function(data)
{
    var htmldata = $(data);
    if(htmldata.find('#ok').val() == "1")
    {
        //some things carried out
    }
});
```

Comment: You are making a jQuery object from a freshly created jQuery object :)